# bash readline: Key binding that executes an external command

Tags: bash, tcsh, readline

(Background: I'm a long-time tcsh user, gradually transitioning to bash, and trying to find equivalents for some useful tcsh-specific features.)

In tcsh, I can define a key binding that executes an external command.  For example, given:

```
bindkey -c ^Gu uptime
```

I can type "Control-G u" in tcsh, and it will execute the `uptime` command.  I don't have to type Enter, the command doesn't appear in my history, and I can do it in the middle of an input line (I find the latter particularly useful for certain commands).

bash has a similar key binding mechanism via the GNU readline library, with bindings specified in `$HOME/.inputrc` (or elsewhere).  But after reading the `info readline` documentation, I don't see a way for a key binding to execute an external command.

The closest thing I've figured out is to add something like this to my `.inputrc` file:

```
"\C-gu": "uptime\n"
```

but that doesn't execute the command; rather, it acts as if I had typed `uptime` followed by the Enter key.  The command appears in my history (that's ok), and it works only on an empty line; if I type `"echo control-Gu"`, then it prints `uptime` rather than executing the command.

Another minor drawback is that the binding affects other commands that use GNU readline, such as the Perl debugger.

Is there a way to simulate the effect of tcsh's `bindkey -c` in bash, by mapping a key sequence to the execution of a specified external command?

If it matters, I'm using bash 4.2.24 on Ubuntu 12.04 beta 2.

Comment: As a long-time user of tcsh myself, I'm curious why you are making the transition (other than perhaps the prevalence of bash shells/users)

Comment: @Levon: bash is installed by default more commonly than tcsh. bash is better for scripting, and it's nice to use the same language for scripting and interactive use.

Comment: All true .. maybe I'll make the switch eventually too (most of my scripts are actually in Python :-) .. but I see your point for sure. Thanks.

Comment: @Levon: And most of my scripts are in Perl,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not all `bash` line editing is controlled from `~/.inputrc`; much of it is configured via the `bind` builtin.  In this case, you want something like

```
bind -x '"\C-gu":uptime'
```

in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  This could well be the final nail in the coffin of my tcsh usage.

Comment: @KeithThompson Or you could switch to zsh, which does this easily, and more generally nabbed pretty much every feature of tcsh and bash.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer provides a solution, that executes the command in a new line. This is useful in some cases, but most of the time my workflow is such, that either I want to

- Insert the result of an inline execute command in my *current* command-line (example below)
- Execute the command truly in the background, no output, no changes in current command line

I use these two principles much more often than the variant @geekosaur showed. Here is an example:

```
bind '"\C-gd":"\C-u`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`\e\C-e\C-a\C-y\C-e"'
```

This bind <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to kill the existing command (saving it in the cut buffer), insert `some shell command`, in this case `date +%Y%m%d%H%M` for a nice timestamp, execute that in-place, and then paste the saved command back to the front of the command-line.

I have a bunch of commands, that output some information from my system, that I regularly use in other command lines, think `get_lan_ip, get_gw_ip, get_gw_pubip, get_ns_ip, get_root_block_dev, get_email_addr, get_phone_number` and so on. Basically like programmable abbreviations! and all of them one key-stroke behind `\C-g` away only.

The other very useful use-case for me is calling functions inline, that *do not* produce output, but silently trigger a background action, like `mediaplayer_next, mediaplayer_pause, speakerphone_answer, ...` for when I want to trigger things without leaving my terminal, and without losing sight of my current windows contents for even a moment ;)

Comment: Very cool, I'll have to play with this. A minor point: I'd use `$(command)` rather than backticks.

Answer (score 2):

To add onto the accepted answer, you don't really need to use `bind -x`. You can still add it to your `inputrc`, but instead of `\n` at the end of your sequence, it has to be the binding for `accept-line`. For example:

```
"\C-m": accept-line
"\C-gu": "uptime\C-m"
```

Since it causes `uptime` to be entered into the commandline, it'll be in your history, which is either an advantage or disadvantage depending on your use-case.

Here `^M` is the carriage return on Mac and Windows, but it doesn't really matter what the sequence is. For example the following works too:

```
"\xxacceptline": accept-line
"\C-gu": "uptime\xxacceptline"
```

Answer (score 0):

To add some tricks you can do with the accepted answer, you can even use something like

```shell
bind -x '"\C-g": echo -en "\e[6t"'
```

to send current window to bottom, or other escape codes invented by xterm to center the window, place window at specific pixel location, etc.

See also `vttest(1)` (it turns out you can learn a lot of fancy escape
sequences just playing around with `vttest`) and https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html